# partition not mounting permanently after installing ubuntu 14.04 on windows primary drive

Tags: 14.04, mount

I installed Ubuntu 14.04LTS on my Windows 8.1 primary drive and after installation completed, the other partition containing my personal files does not mount. It comes up with an error that windows did not shut down properly and the only mount option is read-only.
I also must say that last time i turned off my Windows, it was not responding and I shut it down manually by pressing power button. What should I do Now?

**I mentioned that i installed ubuntu on windows primary partition, that means the windows is removed right now and only the windows loader partition is remained. so there is no windows to sign in and fix the errors!**

Comment: close voters - Read the bold

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned that i installed ubuntu on windows primary partition, that means the windows is removed right now and only the windows loader partition is remained. so there is no windows to sign in and fix the errors!

Comment: Actually this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/532753/280878 helped and resolved the issue. ntfsfix was the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem without using Windows, Mount the drive read only, copy the data to another drive/location, Wipe the drive, repartition and reformat it and copy your data back to it. If you need clarification of this process, comment and tell me how it's unclear and I will elaborate.